# Multiple and query with subrequest. Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I have the following query, I got an error

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "context.branch": "17270" }},
        { "match": { "context.version": "12.0.R2" }},
        { "match": { "run_uid": "AAA / SSS / AA-ContextMenu / 3507031CR3.exe"}},
        {
          "range": {
            "epoch": {
              "lte": 1510340778.78
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
                "mappings": {
                    "_doc": {
                        "properties": {
                            "partition_id": {"type": "integer"},
                            "report_id": {"type": "integer"},
                            "title": {"type": "text"},
                            "epoch": {"type": "date",
                                      "format": "epoch_millis"},
                            "context": {
                                "dynamic": True,
                                "properties": {}
                            },
                            "run_uid": {"type": "text"},
                            "run_id": {"type": "integer"},
                            "build_name": {"type": "text"},
                            "status_id": {"type": "integer"},
                            "rep_custom_id": {"type": "text"},
                            "created": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Could you please tell me why i still see different run_uid? The following options work:

```
    { "match": { "context.branch": "17270" }},
    { "match": { "context.version": "12.0.R2" }}
```

But { "match": { "run_uid": "AAA / SSS / AA-ContextMenu / 3507031CR3.exe"} doesn't work. It return me random run_uids but with correct "context.branch" and 
"context.version"

E.g., I have the following data:

```
run_id context      created

4      blabala132   2019-03-20 08:00:00.0000+0300
5      blabala132   2019-03-20 07:00:00.0000+0300
6      blabala132   2019-03-20 06:00:00.0000+0300
7      blabala132   2019-03-20 05:00:00.0000+0300
8      blabala132   2019-03-20 09:00:00.0000+0300
9      blabala133   2019-03-20 07:00:00.0000+0300
```

Input data: 
run_id 4

The result is the following:

```
5      blabala132   2019-03-20 07:00:00.0000+0300
6      blabala132   2019-03-20 06:00:00.0000+0300
7      blabala132   2019-03-20 05:00:00.0000+0300
```

Each data is less than 2019-03-20 08:00:00.0000+0300 (which belongs to run_id 4) and context is the same.

```
8      blabala132   2019-03-20 09:00:00.0000+0300
```

The above-mentioned string is not in the result since data is gt 2019-03-20 08:00:00.0000+0300 (which belongs to run_id 4)

```
9      blabala133   2019-03-20 07:00:00.0000+0300
```

The above-mentioned string is not in the result since context differs from  blabala132 (which belongs to run_id 4)

Comment: - Your json is not correct
- The es querry syntax is invalid
To start try this.
     {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "run_id": "5000"
                  }
                },
        
                {
                  "range": {
                    "created": {
                      "lte": 1510047258.826,
                      "boost": 2
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }

Comment: For the context, what you try to do? match a json present in your context field (dont name a field context in elastic by the way as this is a kind of keyword), try to retrieve exact sentence maybe (according to your sql request)

Comment: I have fixed the question, could you please help to write the correct query? Seems I need to find by run_id fist, then run another query. Or should I do everything in the 1 query? The problem is a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON structure is incorrect. After that, your query syntax is also not correct. It should be like:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "run_id": 5000
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "context": "{\"branch,keyword\": \"TRT-26878\",\"version\": \"12.0.R2\"}"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created.keyword": {
              "lte": 1510047258.826,
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, let' me check, I have fixed the question. I need to check whether it's a correct query. Seems this query differs from that one which I need. But I can divide that query into 2 parts. Your answer really helped me.

Comment: It seems that you have edited the whole question. Could you provide the mapping of the fields?

Comment: I have added mappings